# Looping through boolean variables

Tags: vb.net, loops, boolean

I have 8 boolean variables and i need to be able to add an email to an email string for each boolean that is true.  I dont't know how to do it without writing a million if statements.  Here is some of what i have:

```
   if bIsBlue then
      strEmailTo = strSalesEmail
      strEmailTo = strEmailTo & ", " & varBlueGrp
   End if
   if bIsRed then
      strEmailTo = strSalesEmail
      strEmailTo = strEmailTo & ", " & varRedGrp
   End if
   if bIsGreen then
      strEmailTo = strSalesEmail
      strEmailTo = strEmailTo & ", " & varGreenGrp
   End if
   if bIsBrown then
      strEmailTo = strSalesEmail
      strEmailTo = strEmailTo & ", " & varBrownGrp                            
   End if
   if bIsBlue and bIsRed then
      strEmailTo = strSalesEmail
      strEmailTo = strEmailTo & ", " & varBlueGrp & ", " & varRedGrp
   End if
   if bIsBlue and bIsGreen then
      strEmailTo = strSalesEmail
      strEmailTo = strEmailTo & ", " & varBlueGrp & ", " & varGreenGrp
   End if
```

Comment: What you need is a lookup table. For each key (Colour) you should store an email group value. At least, you should use a switch statement. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dft2z9yf(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: Also see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I suggest u make the array of those boolean variables and then  iterate threw that so 
u can make a faster access to the all variables.